# Dynamically scale background image

Tags: html, css

All:

I am pretty new to CSS background. I wonder if there is any way that I can resize background image to make it always fill the viewport as possible with only CSS.

The rule is:

> No matter what ratio of the image, it always scale itself just enough to fill the viewport to make sure no empty space left.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BLURRING IMG</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
        body {
            background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/ferns-unsplash.jpg");
            background-position: fixed;
            background-size: 100%, cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And I also want to know **what is the difference** between:

```
background-size: auto auto, cover;
```

and

```
background-size: cover;
```

Thanks

Comment: `background-size:cover` ?

Comment: @Adrew Yes, Johannes help that out too. I give background-size: 100%, cover; that is why it does not work, but I do not know why?

Comment: Simply cause `background-size: 100%, cover;` is WRONG! `cover` cannot be mixed with % or other values. Specially not using comma separation >>> **if you're using only one background-image**.

Comment: So `background` properties, comma separated allow you to add move backgrounds, and likewise to modify each background styles in other properties, again, comma-separated: `background-image: url(), url();` likewise: `background-size: 100% 100%, cover` where `cover` targets the second image-layer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, now I get it. I really need to read tutorial carefully.

Comment: Typo, by *move* I mean *moRe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size: cover`and `background-position: fixed`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I tried that, but it will left blank space, could you give me an Fiddle or codepen to compare?

Comment: I would like a more elaborated answer, something like explaining why this work or browsers compatibility.

Comment: @Kuan, could you provide a fiddle where this doesn't work?

Comment: @Johannes Thanks, I find what is different on my side, I give background-size: 100% 100%, cover; this is what magic happens. But why and how this number affect the cover?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to ask that too.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo  Yes, I will update my question.

Comment: @Kuan `cover`is sufficient for background-size, just erase the 100%. BTW: Also the 100% width and height for body and html don't have any effect, just take them out, and also the overflow:hidden. All this would only work within an element that has `position: fixed` or `absollute`

Comment: @Johannes Thanks, so happy get new knowledge today. This is amazing!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I commented before he edited and posted the code. Just to be fair

Comment: @Andrew ohh oky :) sz

Comment: @Johannes Thanks, I find a attribute from W3school,  only the background-attachment has value fixed like background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: @Johannes I wonder why the background can not scale if no "fixed" value specified?

Comment: @Kuan "fixed" in the "background" rule just means that the background will not _scroll_ together with the contents of the DIV. It has nothing to do with the size. Infos about size are here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for link. I forget to mention that I set overflow to "scroll" and give a very large height to body, and then if I use something like:  background-size: cover;  the background will not auto stretch to cover the background but just repeat itself if I resize the window vertically. But If I  use background-size: cover; and background-attachment: fixed; then the background image will auto stretch. So I guess this "fixed" value affect the how "cover" works